# Schedule a job each night

Tags: linux, python, cron

I am writing a Python script that is built to function as an alarm clock where my computer will randomly select a video file from a folder and play it at the inputted time.

I know I *could* configure it so each night I can just give it an input when I run it and have it sleep until the intended time, but I'd rather not have to rely on the command window staying open all night (mostly because it feels ugly).

I could set it as a cronjob, but the time changes from day to day.  I could have my script set the cronjob (I assume) but that could end up with a backlog of cronjobs.  Maybe I can somehow indicate this specific cronjob as the "alarm" one and then delete the old one, and remake the new one?  I have unrelated cronjobs I wouldn't want my script to touch.

Or maybe there's a totally different solution I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:
https://tecadmin.net/one-time-task-scheduling-using-at-commad-in-linux/

Linux has an `at` command for one-time use scheduling. You can use it like this:

`echo "python alarm.py" | at 8:00 AM`

if you want to run your alarm clock at 8:00.

Write a file, makeAlarm.py, as such:

```
import subprocess
time = input("What time would you like your alarm clock to be set for?:\n")
subprocess.Popen("echo python alarm.py | at " + time)
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Let me know if it doesn't work so we can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have one script, but multiple cron entries - one for each time of day that you want the alarm to happen.

The script itself could be written such that each time it is executed, it chooses at random a file to play.

This would get you the functionality of playing a random file, with the flexibility of choosing what time on each day you want the file to play. You also won't be actively modifying the the crontab file either so there's no risk of clobbering other cron jobs. If you want to change the times when the alarm plays, you'll have to edit the cron jobs manually beforehand.

Comment: It's literally an alarm clock for waking up in the morning--every day might be different depending on what time I want to set it for the night before, and I need it to be simple so I can do it from across the room (wireless keyboard, but my eyes ain't great)

Answer (score 0):

You desktop likely has an "Alarm" widget and Linux being Linux, you can likely have it run a script. On KDE KAlarm will do it. But KAlarm can also play a sound, and you can give the name of a soft link that something else randomly assigns to one of your sounds. Plenty of snooze/repeat options as well.

Comment: Need it to open a video player--added to my question.

Comment: The command it runs can be a script that calls a video player or directly the video player...